# GA measurement protocol tracks event but not enhanced ecommerce purchase

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol, enhanced-ecommerce

I am currently successfully tracking purchases from website using enhanced ecommerce (via GTM).

I have Goals configured that correctly track these in real time. E.g. event goal for Category = Enhanced Ecommerce and Action = transaction.

However, when I try to track purchases using the measurement-protocol I get the event for the enhanced ecommerce, but I can find nothing in conversion (under the goals or otherwise) about the purchase. I am using the [hit-builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder).

I have configured various goals and tried many different variations. In my last attempt I created a goal which should match if the label is equal to "serverevent".

Then I sent this:

```
v=1&t=event&tid=MY_TID&cid=5ca7c46d-a46a-4e0b-a395-b4d1bb228fee&ti=T123415789&ta=test&tr=150&pa=purchase&pr1id=P123459&pr1nm=GiftCard_150&pr1ca=test&cu=EUR&iq=1&ec=Ecommerce&ea=Activation&ni=1&pr1qt=1&el=serverevent
```

In GA I can see the event coming in with event category "Ecommerce", action "Activation" and label "serverevent", but I see nothing in conversions and the goal still has 0 hits.

I have used POSTMAN to post to https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect, and I get back "valid" and "Found 1 hit in the request."

I don't know what else I can try. To be clear I am trying to track server side purchases because these are sales by third parties through our API.

Comment: How long did you wait?

Comment: I was expecting to see something in real time almost immediately, so I was continously checking that. I started tested yesterday.

Comment: Only the real time reports display data in Real time.   For the standard reports you need to wait until the processing is complted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google analytics standard reports take time to process Google stats it can take between 24 -48 hours for the data to complete processing.

You can see if your hits are being recorded by checking the real time api.  As for the standard reports your going to have to wait between 24 - 48 hours to see if the results have completed processing.

Comment: Ok. I was aware of the delay, but was expecting to see something in the realtime for the goals. Today I can see the purchases in conversions.